# Watchkit integrating MediaPlayer.framework using Objective-C

Tags: xcode, watchkit

I want to use MediaPlayer framework into my Watch App.

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

I have added MediaPlayer.framework to my project and I have marked the checkbox AppExtension (on Target Membership), but it is impossible.

Always the same error message:

'MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h' file not found

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use WatchKit's own Media management framework to play media.

For example to play an audio track you can use: `WKAudioFilePlayer`
Instantiate player property like:

```
var player : WKAudioFilePlayer!
```

Then play some track either locally or remotely.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://109.169.26.216:8036/")
player = WKAudioFilePlayer.init(playerItem: WKAudioFilePlayerItem.init(asset: WKAudioFileAsset.init(url: url!)))
```

See, the above example is used for streaming radio stations too. Happy Coding.. :-)

Comment: Not to forget player.play()